# SQL query that should work 1 ms, but it does the job in 5 minutes

Tags: sql

```
SELECT t1.*
                FROM asterisk t1
                WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM asterisk t2
                              WHERE t2.id <> t1.id
                              AND t2.unique_id = t1.unique_id
                              AND t1.operator_dial = '203'
                              AND t1.event = 'Dial'
                              AND t2.event = 'Bridge'
                              AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM asterisk t3
                                          WHERE t3.id <> t1.id
                                          AND t2.unique_id = t3.unique_id
                                          AND t1.operator_dial = '203'
                                          AND t3.event = 'Unlink'))
                ORDER BY date DESC
                LIMIT 1
```

Need help to make it work fast, is it possible? My head ready to explode trying to understand what it should do. (Table has ~5k records)
Description for that query is: "Look if there is a Dial events, after which comes Bridge events, but no Unlink events".

Comment: Your tables have indexes?

Comment: Correlated subqueries aren't terribly performant. Try `left join`s.

Comment: `LIMIT 1` and `ORDER BY` tend to negate each-other (speed wise).  You still need to go through everything to figure out the top record.

Comment: There are indexes: id, event, unique_id.

Comment: Would it make a diffenrece to put the `t1.operator_dial = '203'`-condition into an outer `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Why do you think the query should be answerable in 1 ms?  On what basis do you consider that to be possible?

Comment: Thanks all guys, this works now in ~0.0017 ms.

Comment: possible duplicate of [One more SQL query that should work under 0.1 ms, but it does the job in 5 minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235672/one-more-sql-query-that-should-work-under-0-1-ms-but-it-does-the-job-in-5-minut)

Comment: `Look if there is a Dial events, after which comes Bridge events, but no Unlink events".` Please define *after* (I do not see any attempt in the query to guarantee such an ordering of events)

Comment: A description of the relevant table fields should have been in the question from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using joins instead of exists.

```
SELECT t1 * 
FROM asterisk t1
INNER JOIN asterisk t2 on t1.id=t2.id
    AND t2.unique_id = t1.unique_id
    AND t1.operator_dial = '203'
    AND t1.event = 'Dial'
    AND t2.event = 'Bridge'
LEFT OUTER JOIN asterisk t3 on t2.unique_id=t3.unique_id
    AND t3.id <> t1.id
    AND t1.operator_dial = '203'
            AND t3.event = 'Unlink'
WHERE t3.id IS NULL
            ORDER BY date DESC
            LIMIT 1
```

Also, take a look at the [Explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html) to see what piece is causing the query to take so long and to confirm indexes are being used.

Comment: should probably do `OUTER JOIN asterisk t2 on t1.id<>t2.id`  I think you can do that.  and the same with `t2.id` and `t3.id`  at least that is what I am thinking from looking at OP's Code.  my bad @cars10 is right.

Comment: @Malachi An `INNER JOIN` of `t2`and `t3` would kill the rows we are looking for.

Comment: Emphasis added: "Look if there is a Dial events, *after which* comes Bridge events". There's no guarantee here that the bridge event occurs after the dial event. *However*, the question's query did not fulfill this condition either.

Answer (score 0):

If I have not missed something, your query should look like this:

```
select t1.*
from asterisk as t1
where
    t1.operator_dial = '203' and
    t1.event = 'Dial' and
    exists (
        select *
        from asterisk as t2
        where
            t2.id <> t1.id and t2.unique_id = t1.unique_id
            t2.event = 'Bridge' and t2.date > t1.date
    ) and
    not exists
    (
        select *
        from asterisk as t3
        where
            t3.id <> t1.id and t3.unique_id = t1.unique_id and
            t3.event = 'Unlink' and t3.date > t1.date
    )
order by t1.date desc
limit 1
```

but it would be great for performace if you have indexes (on operator_dial and event, and on date)

Comment: Emphasis added: "Look if there is a Dial events, *after which* comes Bridge events". There's no guarantee here that the bridge event occurs after the dial event. *However*, the question's query did not fulfill this condition either.

Comment: missed that description

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Asterisk t1
INNER JOIN Asterisk t2
  ON t1.unique_id = t2.unique_id
  AND t2.date > t1.date
  AND t2.event = 'Bridge'
LEFT JOIN Asterisk t3
  ON t1.unique_id = t3.unique_id
  AND t3.event = 'Unlink'
WHERE t1.operator_dial = '203'
  AND t1.event = 'Dial'
  AND t3.id IS NULL
ORDER BY t1.date
LIMIT 1
```

Note that I have omitted t1.id <> t2.id. The event and date clauses will enforce this condition implicitly.

> Look if there is a Dial events, after which comes Bridge events, but no Unlink events

I have assumed that "no unlink events" means none at all, though your requirement could be read as "no unlink events occurring after the dial event". If the latter is the case, you can add t3.date > t1.date to the join in order to change the functionality.